# Looking for Guidance

Tags: database-design

I'm currently working on an online test application with limited answer time etc. The biggest problem for me is to design the database. I have couple ideas, but I'm experiencing many of implementation issues while managing the data.

General idea:

Users are divided into groups. One user may belong to more than one group.
Tests are assigned to groups  of users. One test may be assigned to more than one group.

The tricky part for me is how to represent the relation. Whether to stack id's of groups separated with eg. ',' in a column of users table or not. Same goes for tests. If I do as I wrote above, there will be some searching difficulties.

I just need a direction to work on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each of User, Group, and Test you'd need a table.

For each of the many-to-many relationships between them, you'd need another table.

So what you're likely to end up with are tables for:

- users
- groups
- tests
- user_groups
- test_groups

Avoid placing multiple values in a single cell in order to establish the relationship -- a separate table is the standard method.